# Failed to connect to OpenOffice headless mode

Tags: python, openoffice.org, uno

I am trying to convert one file format to another using PyODConverter(DocumentConverter.py)

I have installed OpenOffice headless as a service .

When I am trying to do : `python DocumentConverter.py      test.ppt test.odf`

Its showing an error :

```
ERROR! failed to connect to OpenOffice.org on port 8100
```

Help! I am in Ubuntu .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Are you/ have you specifying the hostname with port number?
- If have used localhost then try to change it to 127.0.0.1
- Is network using a proxy or is there a fire wall blocking it?

Can you start open openOffice manually and check the OpenOffice process info from the console with 
'ps auxw | greg office'

It should contain info about host and port. 
And last question is this what your start looks like for OpenOffice in server mode?

$OOFFICE "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" -norestore -nofirststartwizard -nologo -headless  &

When you say...
I have installed OpenOffice headless as a service.
..do you mean you have installed oo and configured setup.xcu
..or installed a extension to start in server mode
..you are starting oo via consol or bash scrip with launch string

Also if are using oo version <2.0 you must have x11 running or have xvfb running.